Given that $a+b-1 \mid a^2+b^2-1$, prove that $a+b-1$ is composite $(a,b>1)$
What I've managed to show is that since $$a^2+b^2-1+2ab=(a+b+1)(a+b-1)$$ it follows $$a+b-1 \vert 2ab$$
Also $a+b-1$ cannot divide $2$ because $a+b-1 \geq$ 3, thus $$a+b-1\vert ab$$ I tried to apply the formula $$gcd(x,y)\cdot lcm(x,y)=x\cdot y$$ to evaluate $gcd(a+b-1,\cdot)$ but no luck.

$(a+b+1)(a+b-1)=a^2+b^2+2ab-1$, not what you wrote.  Though I don't think that changes the divisibility $(a+b-1),|,2ab$.

if $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b.$  $(a+b-1)$ cannot divide $a$ because $a+b+1 >a.$ for the same reason it cannot divide $b.$  You have already shown that it cannot divide 2, so you are done.

I don't see how you deduce that $(a+b-1),|,ab$.  For instance  $(2+3-1),|,(2\times 2\times 3)$ but $(2+3-1), \nmid (2\times 3)$.

@user317176  But I don't think the OP's claim that $(a+b-1),|,ab$ has been established.

@user317176  Of course, if $a+b-1$ is even, then it is composite.

Sorry for not clarifying. I was assuming that $(a,b)$ have same parity, otherwise $a+b-1$ would be composite as someone already said. So with this assumption $a+b-1\mid ab$

Suppose $a+b+1|a^2+b^2 - 1$
$a^2+b^2 - 1 = (a+b+1)(a+b-1) - 2ab$
$p|pq + r \implies p|r$
$a+b+1|2ab$
If $p$ is prime $p|ab \implies p|a$ or $p|b.$  This is one way to define prime.
If $a+b+1 | 2ab$ then $a+b+1 | a$ or $a+b+1|b$ or $a+b+1 | 2$
But each of these is impossible if $a,b \ge 2$
It is inconsistent that $a+b+1 | a^2+b^2 - 1$ and $a+b+1$ is prime.

Seems right. Can't believe I missed such a simple solution. Thank you.

Assume $(a+b-1){\,\mid\,}(a^2+b^2-1)$, where $a,b$ are integers with $a,b > 1$.

Then $a+b-1\ge 3$, so $a+b-1$ is either composite or an odd prime.

Our goal is to show that $a+b-1$ is composite.

Suppose instead that $a+b-1=p$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

Then from $a+b-1=p$ we get $b\equiv 1-a\;(\text{mod}\;p)$, hence
\begin{align*}
&
(a+b-1){\,\mid\,}(a^2+b^2-1)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^2+b^2-1\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^2+(1-a)^2-1\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2a(a-1)\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a(a-1)\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)
&&\bigl(\text{since $p$ is odd}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}a\;\,\text{or}\;\,p{\,\mid\;}(a-1)
&&\bigl(\text{since $p$ is prime}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
But we have
$$
1\le a-1 < a < p
$$
so we can't have $p{\,\mid\,}a\;\,\text{or}\;\,p{\,\mid\;}(a-1)$.

Thus we have a contradiction.

It follows that $a+b-1$ is composite.
